# VM filesystem backup + SAP HANA Backup for a single VM

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I am trying to configure Azure Backup for a VM that is running HANA database.
The goal is to have filesystem backup for OS disk and HANA workload backup enabled for the same VM.

What I can see, is that there is no possiblitiy to use 2 resources of type azurerm_backup_protected_vm for the same virtual machine.

Terraform version: 1.5.4
azurerm provider version: 3.71.0

Current state:

- policy for filesystem backup (with exclusion of /hana/data and /hana/log disks) is created and linked to a VM with azurerm_backup_protected_vm resource.
- policy for HANA backup is created

While trying to use another azurerm_backup_protected_vm pointing to HANA backup policy, the apply fails with an error saying that resource with certain ID already exists (this is the filesystem backup protected item)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgAXw.png)

QUESTION:
Is it possible to attach 2 backup policies to a single VM?
Is it possible to use separate Recovery Services Vaults for attaching multiple policies to single VM? Or is there another way to make it work?

Code for policies:

```
# Backup Vault and Policy
resource "azurerm_recovery_services_vault" "backup" {
  name                          = var.recovery_service_vault.name
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.backup.name
  location                      = var.location
  sku                           = var.recovery_service_vault.sku
  soft_delete_enabled           = var.recovery_service_vault.soft_delete_enabled
  public_network_access_enabled = var.recovery_service_vault.public_network_access_enabled
  storage_mode_type             = var.recovery_service_vault.storage_mode_type
  tags                          = var.tags
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

}


resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm" "vm_db" {
  for_each                        = var.backup_policy_vm_db
  name                            = each.value.name
  resource_group_name             = azurerm_resource_group.backup.name
  recovery_vault_name             = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup.name
  instant_restore_retention_days  = each.value.instant_restore_retention_days
  timezone                        = "UTC"

  backup {
    frequency = each.value.backup.frequency
    time      = each.value.backup.time
  }

  retention_daily {
    count = each.value.retention_daily_count
  }

}

resource "azurerm_backup_policy_vm_workload" "hana" {
  for_each            = var.backup_policy_hana
  name                = each.value.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.backup.name
  recovery_vault_name = azurerm_recovery_services_vault.backup.name

  workload_type = "SAPHanaDatabase"

  settings {
    time_zone           = "UTC"
    compression_enabled = false
  }

  #Full backup
  protection_policy {
    policy_type = each.value.full.policy_type

    backup {
      frequency = each.value.full.frequency
      weekdays  = each.value.full.weekdays
      time      = each.value.full.time
    }

    retention_weekly {
      count    = each.value.full.retention_weekly
      weekdays = each.value.full.weekdays
    }
  }

  #Incremental backup
  protection_policy {
    policy_type = each.value.incr.policy_type

    backup {
      frequency = each.value.incr.frequency
      weekdays  = each.value.incr.weekdays
      time      = each.value.incr.time
    }

    simple_retention {
      count    = each.value.incr.retention_daily
    }
  }

  #Log backup
  protection_policy {
    policy_type = each.value.log.policy_type

    backup {
      frequency_in_minutes = each.value.log.frequency_in_minutes
    }

    simple_retention {
      count = each.value.log.simple_retention
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "db" {
  depends_on          = [time_sleep.db]
  resource_group_name = var.backup_policy_db.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_services_vault.name
  source_vm_id        = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.db.id
  backup_policy_id    = var.backup_policy_db.id
  exclude_disk_luns   = concat(tolist(azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.data[*].lun), tolist(azurerm_virtual_machine_data_disk_attachment.log[*].lun))
}

resource "azurerm_backup_protected_vm" "hana" {
  depends_on          = [time_sleep.db]
  resource_group_name = var.backup_policy_db.resource_group_name
  recovery_vault_name = var.recovery_services_vault.name
  source_vm_id        = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.db.id
  backup_policy_id    = var.backup_policy_hana.id
}
```